# How do I use the apply or applymap to translate results of a function on a new column and store the results in a string?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert values of the age column into a frequency distribution.

I defined a function that would translate each age value into the specified frequency and stored in a string.

```
# create a new column AgeGroup that stores age in frequencies
def age_cat_col(age):

    if renmoney['age'] <= 20:
        return 'Below 20 yrs'
    elif (renmoney['age'] > 20) & (renmoney['age'] <= 30):
        return 'Between 21 and 30 yrs'
    elif (renmoney['age'] > 30) & (renmoney['age'] <= 40):
        return 'Between 31 and 40 yrs'
    elif (renmoney['age'] > 40) & (renmoney['age'] <= 50):
        return 'Between 41 and 50 yrs'
    elif (renmoney['age'] > 50) & (renmoney['age'] <= 60):
        return 'Between 51 and 60 yrs'
    elif (renmoney['age'] > 60) & (renmoney['age'] <= 70):
        return 'Between 61 and 70 yrs'
    elif (renmoney['age'] > 70) & (renmoney['age'] <= 80):
        return 'Between 71 and 80 yrs'
    elif (renmoney['age'] > 80) & (renmoney['age'] <= 90):
        return 'Between 81 and 90 yrs'
    elif (renmoney['age'] > 90) & (renmoney['age'] <= 100):
        return 'Between 91 and 100 yrs'
    elif renmoney['age'] > 100:
        return 'Above 100 yrs'

renmoney['AgeGroup'] = renmoney.apply(lambda age: age_cat_col(age), axis = 1)
```

I just want each age value to be stored as a string.
E.g. if the age is 43, it would be stored as 'Between 41 and 50 yrs'.

Comment: unrelated: half of your conditions are obsolete:  `if renmoney['age'] <= 20:` means that `elif (renmoney['age'] > 20) & (renmoney['age'] <= 30):` can be shortened to `elif renmoney['age'] <= 30:` - because if it was less then 20 the first condition would have matched .... at least if you use those conditions in this exact order of increasing upper limit. And if not: `elif 20 < renmoney['age'] <= 30:` is a viable shorthand. Beside that - you pass in the age - so `20 < age <=30` should be it

Comment: just remove single quote from age inside your function, i.e  renmoney[age]

Comment: @qua `renmoney["age"]`  is (incorrectly) used to adress the dataframes "age" column - you can replace `renmoney["age"]` with `age` as the columncontent is fed into the function already

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your function as a scalar conversion (which is advised, as your dataframe name is now hard-wired inside your current function definition) and then use `.applymap()`. Example:

1. Scalar function definition

```
def age_cat_col(age):

    if age <= 20:
        return 'Below 20 yrs'
    elif (age > 20) & (age <= 30):
        return 'Between 21 and 30 yrs'
    elif (age > 30) & (age <= 40):
        return 'Between 31 and 40 yrs'
    elif (age > 40) & (age <= 50):
        return 'Between 41 and 50 yrs'
    elif (age > 50) & (age <= 60):
        return 'Between 51 and 60 yrs'
    elif (age > 60) & (age <= 70):
        return 'Between 61 and 70 yrs'
    # and so on
```

Note: You can skip a lot of these lines by defining the function as Aryerez has written.

2. Use `.applymap()` (or just `.map()` if you handle a single `pd.Series`)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'age':[15,26,50]})
df.applymap(age_cat_col)
```

This will output:

```
                      age
0   Below 20 yrs
1   Between 21 and 30 yrs
2   Between 41 and 50 yrs
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to pass the whole row to *age_cat_col* function. You only have to pass age column. The code should look like that:

```
def age_cat_col(age):
   if age <= 20:
     return 'Below 20 yrs'
   elif (age > 20) & (age <= 30):
     return 'Between 21 and 30 yrs'
   elif (age > 30) & (age <= 40):
    .....


 renmoney['AgeGroup'] = renmoney['age'].apply(age_cat_col)
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would save a lot of typing (and also run-time) with:

```
df['age_cat'] = df['age'].map(lambda x: 'Below 20 yrs' if x <= 20 else \
     (('Between ' + str((x - 1) // 10) + '1 and ' + str((x + 9) // 10) + '0 yrs') if x <= 100 else 'Above 100 yrs'))
```